# IE doesn't recognize my media queries

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, media-queries

In other browsers it recognize and functional but it seems IE doesn't recognize my media queries. Is there anything wrong with my codes ? I've done one similar design like this one, there is no problem but this one is confusing. Why it doesn't recognize ?

Here is the css:

```css
/* This css is for small Mobile Devices */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  a, a:focus, a:hover, a:active {outline: 0;}
 .slogan h2 {padding: 10px 0px;font-size: 18px;}
 .navbar-header a {padding: 14px 0;}
 .left_content_video {float: none;}
 .right_content_video {float: none;}
 .left_content_video {float: none;}
 .right_content_video {float: none;padding-bottom: 4px;}
 .left_content_video {margin-right: 0px;margin-bottom: 30px;padding-bottom: 5px;}
 .navbar-nav {margin: 0px;}
 .single_content_btm_ico {margin-bottom: 30px;}
 .content_videos h1 {margin-left: 14px;}
 .navbar-form {display: none;}
 .open > .dropdown-menu {
 /*customization*/
 display: block;}
 .video_panel {}
 .video_panel h1 {background: #23262a none repeat scroll 0 0;font-size: 15px;padding: 12px 10px;}
 .clip_content {width: 100%;background: #FFFFFF;margin-bottom: 30px;}
 .video_panel_maincontent_1 h1, .video_panel_maincontent_2 h1, .video_panel_maincontent_3 h1, .video_panel_maincontent_4 h1 {margin-left: 15px;color: #ddd;display: inline-block;}

}

/* This css is for Tablet Devices */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 a, a:focus, a:hover, a:active {outline: 0;border: none;}
 .slogan h2 {padding-top: 32px;}
 .logo img {padding: 12px 0px 0px;}
 .dropdown-toggle, .divider {display: none;}
 .navbar-header a {padding: 27px 0;}
 .videos {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 30px;
   width: 185px;}
   .left_content_video {
   margin-bottom: 30px;}
   .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
   min-height: 1px;
   padding-left: 33px;
   padding-right: 15;
   position: relative;}
 .left_content_video {float: left;}
 .right_content_video {float: right;}
 .left_content_video {margin-right: 5px;}
 .slider {margin-top: 30px;}
 .content_videos {margin-top: 30px;}
 .navbar-nav {margin: 0 50px 0px;}
 .twitter_box:hover {background: #B32D45;}
 .facebook_box:hover {background: #B32D45;}
 .google_box:hover {background: #B32D45;}
 .content_videos h1 {margin-left: 31px;}

 li.dropdown:hover > a.dropdown-toggle {background:#333;}

 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {display: block;margin-top: 0; // remove the gap so it doesn't close}
 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
 /*customization*/
 /*color: #333;*/
 background-color: #61D8A2;
 display: block;}
 .dropdown-menu > li > a {background-color: #2C2C2C;}
 li.dropdown:hover > a.dropdown-toggle{
 background:#2C2C2C;}
 .dropdown-menu > li > a {border-bottom: 1px solid #3c3c3c;}
 .video_panel {margin-left: 175;}
 .clip_content {width: 100%;height: 385px;background: #FFFFFF;margin-bottom: 30px;}
 .navbar-form {display: none;}
}

/* This css is for Medium Devices */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
 a, a:focus, a:hover, a:active {outline: 0;border: none;}
 .slogan h2 {padding: 37px 0px;}
 .dropdown-toggle, .divider {display: none;}
 .navbar-nav {padding-left: 100px;}
 .navbar-header a {padding: 27px 0;}
 .videos {width: 185px;}
 .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
   min-height: 1px;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-right: 15px;
   position: relative;}
 .slider {margin-top: 30px;}
 .navbar-nav {margin: 0px;}
 .twitter_box:hover {background: #B32D45;}
 .facebook_box:hover {background: #B32D45;}
 .google_box:hover {background: #B32D45;}
 .content_videos h1 {margin-left: 14px;}
 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
 /*customization*/
 /*color: #333;*/
 background-color: #61D8A2;
 display: block;}
 .dropdown-menu > li > a {background-color: #2C2C2C;}
 li.dropdown:hover > a.dropdown-toggle{
 background:#2C2C2C;}
 .dropdown-menu > li > a {border-bottom: 1px solid #3c3c3c;}
 .video_panel {margin-left: 235px;}
 .clip_content {width: 100%;height: 165px;background: #FFFFFF;margin-bottom: 30px;}
 .video_panel_maincontent_1 h1, .video_panel_maincontent_2 h1, .video_panel_maincontent_3 h1, .video_panel_maincontent_4 h1 {margin-left: 15px;}
}

/* This css is for Large Devices */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
 a, a:focus, a:hover, a:active {outline: 0;border: none;}
 .slogan h2 {padding: 37px 0px;}
 .logo img {padding: 12px 0px;}
 .dropdown-toggle, .divider {display: none;}
 .navbar-nav {padding-left: 150px;}
 .dropdown-menu > li > a {border-bottom: 1px solid #3c3c3c;}
 .navbar-header a {padding: 27px 0;}
 .navbar-nav li ul li a:hover,
 .navbar-nav li ul li a:focus,
 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
 /*customization*/
 /*color: #333;*/
 background-color: #61D8A2;
 display: block;}
 .slider {margin-top: 30px;}
 .videos {width: 235px;}
 .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;}
 .slider {margin-top: 30px;}
 .navbar-nav {margin: 0px;}
 .twitter_box:hover {background: #B32D45;}
 .facebook_box:hover {background: #B32D45;}
 .google_box:hover {background: #B32D45;}
 .content_videos h1 {margin-left: 14px;}
 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
 /*customization*/
 /*color: #333;*/
 background-color: #61D8A2;
 display: block;}
 .dropdown-menu > li > a {background-color: #2C2C2C;}
 li.dropdown:hover > a.dropdown-toggle{
  background:#2C2C2C;}
  .video_panel {margin-left: 300px;}
  .video_panel_maincontent h1 {padding: 15px;display: block;border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;}
  .video_panel_maincontent_1 h1, .video_panel_maincontent_2 h1, .video_panel_maincontent_3 h1, .video_panel_maincontent_4 h1 {margin-left: 15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #BAC0C4;display: block;width: 1140px;;color: #BAC0C4}
  .clip_content {width: 100%;height: 202px;background: #FFFFFF;margin-bottom: 30px;}
}
```

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognizing?" What's happening that you don't expect to happen. Also, you can drop the `@media (max-width:767px)`, you don't need it as you call `min-width` for everything larger.

Comment: Ok, I figure it out @disinfor I was trying to modify my css using media queries so I've included 4 media queries separately unfortunately same media (min-width: 1200px) and media (min-width: 992px) viewport were at bootstrap.css so it was conflicting and that's why IE doesn't recognize these 2 media queries. So I just exclude these two media queries from bootstrap and add it in my responsive.css. Now it's working perfectly. I'm new in bootstrap so I just couldn't figure out this simple issue :)

Comment: Hello @Saji. Could you  turn your comment into an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

Check if you already have this line of code in head of html, Cause sometime people forget to write this single line which result in media queries not working..

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```